# Display data from Table 1 after verifying column from table 1,table 2 and table3

Tags: c#, sql

I have three table, table a, b, c
table a does not have any link with table c, table b have one same column in table a and one column same as in table c
How to display data in table a by filtering the two column from table a and table B, table b and c

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to filter `a`, I would recommend `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from b join
                   c
                   on b.colb = c.colb
              where b.cola = a.cola
             );
```

The advantage of this approach over `join` is that it does not return duplicate values when there are multiple matches.  Your question specifies that you want to "display a" filtered by the other tables. This does exactly what you are specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Two `JOIN`s would achieve what you want efficiently. For instance:

```
SELECT  TableA.Value1,
        TableA.Value2
FROM    TableA
JOIN    TableB
ON      TableB.KeyColumn = TableA.TableBKey
JOIN    TableC
ON      TableC.KeyColumn = TableB.TableCKey
```

This returns records in `TableA` with a reference to a record in `TableB`, which in turn has a reference to a record in `TableC`

There are other alternatives using `LEFT JOIN` (return all records in `TableA`, and referenced records from `TableB` *if they exist*, as opposed to *only* records in `TableA` that reference records in `TableB`), and `OUTER JOIN` etc

Wikipedia actually has some [decent JOIN documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), along with good explanatory Venn diagrams.